# How to order GridViewcolumnHeaders with custom method?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have SortableListView.In it there is Gridview and GridViewColumns.After closing project i save to xml each GridViewColumn's index.And want to when project ran it is restored.but there is no property to set GridViewColumn's index .How to do this?or is there any way to order GridViewColumns' headers to this indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to do that - you have to reorder the column collection. 
It is probably easiest is to insert them in the right order.